# How to change font color for comments in Vim

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim

I'd like to change the default font color for comments, which is dark blue to slightly yellow color. It is difficult to read on the black background. I'm using xfce4-terminal, not gvim with GUI.

How do I change only this one color?

So far, I have changed the settings in my `~/.profile` file according to "[256 colors in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim)" using:

```
if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
        export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
        export TERM='xterm-color'
fi
```

and

```
set t_Co=256
```

in `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Just a stupid question, did you try the different builtin colorschemes? Try for example `:colorscheme desert`. Tab-completion should work usually.

Comment: I tried it. But I'd like to achieve more customization. If nobody knows this answer, I will accept yours as the best solution, because you answered before I made my question more specific according to what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Can't you reassign the color palette of the terminal? Doesn't the terminal have any settings?

Comment: @Benoit See next revision of the question.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
:hi Comment guifg=#ABCDEF
```

Pick your color! If using a color terminal, replace `guifg=#ABCDEF` with `ctermfg=N` with N being a color number.

Also type `:help :hi` for more information.

Comment: Thank you. ctermfg works with colors like green or yellow. But if I will give it #ABCDEF or ABCDEF it writes error `E421: color name or number not recognized` . It doesn't recognize letters in hexadecimal code, it recognizes only numbers.

Comment: yes, the `guifg` parameter is for when you use vim gui (gvim).

Comment: That means that I'm restricted to only 16 colors? I added the setting to `.vimrc` but this doesn't work `set highlight Comment ctermfg=yellow`

Comment: @xral: your terminal has a limited number of colors. If you want to stay in the terminal then only the colors available in your terminal are available in vim, typically this is 16.

Comment: There are more than 16. See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim). I want to achieve that my comments are yellow but only slightly yellow and forever. Is it possible to set this in `.vimrc`?

Comment: I tried putting this in my .vimrc, but it is being ignored unless I enter it manually.  Once upon a time, I remember having custom colors set up (at another job), but I think it was in a different dot-file :-(

Comment: @Roboprog I have the same problem! If I enter the command manually in vim it's working OK, if I put it in ~.vimrc it shows the new color first, but then when I only move the cursor once the color of comments changes to the default one... Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: This is two years too late, but in case anyone else is wanting the solution to @Roboprog 's problem. Mine was ignoring it when i put the line `hi comment ctermfg=<colour>` into the `.vimrc` file, but i worked out it was because that line came before the line `syntax on`, once i swapped the order, it worked fine..

Answer (score 153):

Most well-behaving colorschemes will respect the `background` setting.

```
set background=dark
```

would change the color of comments from dark blue to light blue, when using the default colorscheme.

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Maybe not the best answer to the question above, but solved the "very difficult to read" proble ina perfect way.

Comment: This should be the default on Ubuntu. Comments are basically impossible to read when dark blue on the purple background. Thanks. I included this in my `~/.vimrc` file. If someone wants to test what this looks like without doing that, just type the above command into vim after pressing the `:` key.

Comment: That was the first thing a google search turned up.  However, I like the default colors (other than comments) which work well both in the dark terminal window and when pasted into an email/doc with a white background.  I like a dark terminal, what can I say?  (nostalgia/custom)

Comment: adding the line 'set background=dark' to ~/.vimrc did the trick.  my eyes got so use to the other colour scheme, my brain thinks this looks ugly... but at least i can see my comments now.  Thanks.

Comment: @3kstc: you can add it to your `~/.vimrc` as-is. You can also preview what happens in the current session only by typing it in command mode. (In normal mode, type `:` to enter command mode.)

Answer (score 61):

```
hi Comment ctermfg=LightBlue
```

Add this to your `.vimrc` file which is either in your `~` or the `/etc/vim` directory. This will make it permanent. I haven't tested this with gvim.

I also have `set background=light` before I set comment color. I like all the colors it created except for the comments.

Comment: Where does `LightBlue` come from?

Comment: this worked for me only when I put it at the **end** of .vimrc

Comment: @user3342981 Location shouldn't matter. You must have something else in the configuration file that changes this variable. So putting it at the end ensured yours setting was the final one interpreted.

Comment: I figure I need to put it after `syntax on` for it to work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I had to add `syntax on` and to modify `set background=dark` and `hi Comment ctermfg=119` to see comment in aqua color...

Comment: I found Lightblue on black still almost unreadable. '119' turned out to be better. YMMV.

Answer (score 10):

After searching you can find a decent reference to Vim regarding this issue especially, at "[256 colors in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim)".

Start with:

```
:verbose hi
```

when actually inside Vim, and editing a file.

Then check out how all of the variables have metadata associated with them. Data returned from there makes it real easy to add the desired modifier types into .vimrc. As an example, these are updates I recently added in order to get rid of dark blue, and not have to be tormented by the light blue:

```
set number background=dark
syntax on
highlight Comment    ctermfg=119
highlight Identifier ctermfg=99AA00
```

Answer (score 7):

If the objective is to make it more readable in the dark background of the text console, the command below is a wonderful option and easy to remember:

```
:colorscheme evening
```

But be advised, it will change other element's colors.

Answer (score 5):

See "[Syntax Highlighting In VIm](http://www.idimmu.net/2012/10/02/syntax-highlighting-in-vim/)".

```
set background=dark
```

or

```
set bg=dark
```

are the best solution for VIM users!

Answer (score 1):

There are various color schemes in Vim. The "default" color scheme displays comments in a blue color, which makes it hard to read against a black terminal background. I prefer to use the "desert" color scheme which displays in readable colors.

To enable the "desert" color scheme in Vim, use the command `:color desert`. If you want to go back to the default use `:color default`.

You can even update your `~/.vimrc` with your preferred color scheme using:

```
echo 'color desert' >> ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your color scheme first using:

```
:!ls $VIMRUNTIME/colors
```

then try whichever suits you best.

Comment: This might be useful if it states how to try the scheme.  I could look it up, but the information should be self contained.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and wanted to edit my Comment color from LightBlue to something more toned down, and, following @Benoit's answer, this worked for me:

```
hi Comment ctermbg=0 ctermfg=DarkGrey
```

I saved it in my ~/.vimrc file.

`0` = Black Background, i.e. Color Terminal Background: `ctermbg=0`, and the Foreground text is `DarkGrey`, i.e. Color Terminal Foreground: `ctermfg=DarkGrey`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. While your answer may be helpful it is badly formatted (try to use code formatting tools) and lacks source references (how would anyone know who **Benoit** is).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read "[answer]" and its linked pages, along with "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)".